# DateTime field throws error in Expression Tree based query generator for EFCore 3.1.1

Tags: c#, datetime, tree, runtime, expression

I have a query generator based on C# Expression Trees which I use it to feed the Where condition of a IQueryable in EFCore 3.1. The mechanism is that it parses an object called FilterCriterion within which it included auto properties such as Field of type string, Value of type object, OperationExpression of type enum. In the last point of generating Expression object just before it is chained to Lambda>, I have a method like this:

```
    private static Expression 
   GetConstantExpressionWithProperOperatorSpecified(Type 
   lastInnerType, 
     MemberExpression memberExpression, object propertyValue, 
    OperationExpression 
      operationToCheckWith)
     {
        Expression result = null;
        MethodInfo contains = null;
        switch (operationToCheckWith)
        {
            case OperationExpression.Equals:
                if (TypeHelper.GetTypeAliasName(lastInnerType) == 
    "DateTime" || 
                    TypeHelper.GetTypeAliasName(lastInnerType) == 
    "DateTime?")
                {
                    var dateTimeVariable = 
   Expression.Variable(lastInnerType);
                    var res = Expression.Assign(dateTimeVariable, 
   Expression.Constant(propertyValue, 
                              lastInnerType));
                    result = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, 
    dateTimeVariable);

                }
                else
                {
                    result = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, 
 Expression.Constant(propertyValue, 
   lastInnerType));
                }
                break;
     ...
   }
```

And in the code which is the client of this method, when it reaches to the Count() method:

```
 var dbSet = ((CRMNewDbContext)_orderDbContext).Orders;
 IQueryable<Order> queryable = null;
 var findCriteria = (OrderFindCriteria)orderFindCriteria;
 queryable = ApplyIncludes(dbSet);
 var filteredQueryable = ApplyCriteriaOnQueryable(queryable, 
  findCriteria);
  filteredQueryable = ApplySortCriteria(filteredQueryable, 
  findCriteria.Sorts);
  var total = filteredQueryable.Count();
```

it produces the error:
               Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')'

I would hope that it worked just like when as regular we type the expression by hand in the code like this:

```
  var rightVal = Convert.ToDateTime("2020-02-27");
  orderQueryable = orderQueryable.Where(order => 
  order.OrderDate == rightVal);
```

Any help on resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: I have found that it is to do the fact that because the underlying database type is datetime, and also has the time section, so the EF gets confused in conversion of type DateTime of CLR to its equivalent  datetime of sql server. To workaround this I created an ef core console and try to simulate the condition which I came across. First the migration created datetime2 from Order model. Then I changed OrderDate data type in sql server to date and it omitted the time section. And finally when I built the expression of Where condition, it worked fine. At this point I felt closer to the solution.

Comment: Converting the underlying database field to datetime2 is also a cure to the already existed tables. So EF can  clnvert from datetime2 and also date easily to DateTime type of CLR, but if table field in databse is datetime, it will produce a conversion failed exception.